# String return statement JS

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I'm working on a JS exercise and it semi works but it's not returning a statement when the last conditional is satisfied, only an empty set of parenthesis. I'm not too sure why but any help is appreciated!

```
function isItANum(str) {
  var phonenum = str.replace(/[^0-9]+/g,"");

  if(str.length===11 && str.indexOf(0)===0) {
    str = str;

  } else if (str.match(/[a-z]/i)) {
    str = phonenum;

  } else {
    str = "Not a phone number";
  }

  return str;
}

isItANum("hey");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply step through the calculation in order.

First, there are no digits in `hey`, so the variable `phonenum` gets replaced with an empty string when it reaches `str.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");`.

Second, you check if the length is `11`, and if the first character isn't a `0`. That fails, so it steps into the `else if`.

Third, `hey` matches the regex `/[a-z]/i`, so `str` is set to `phonenum`.

Fourth, `str` (now `phonenum`) gets returned, and is an empty string.

To actually return `"Not a phone number"`, simply remove the `else if` entirely; the non-digits will already be stripped by the first regex. That way, when the `if` fails, it will go straight to the `else`. You can combine the length and starting `0` validation in the same conditional.

Note that you're probably actually looking for the regex `/^[a-z]/i` to ensure that it only contains lowercase characters (note the starting carat). And for what it's worth, the first `if` calculation is unnecessary, as `str` is **already** exactly equal to `str`.

This can be re-written as the following:

```js
function isItANum(str) {
  var phonenum = str.replace(/[^0-9]+/g,"");
  if (str.length === 11 && str.indexOf(0) === 0 && str.match(/[^a-z]/i)) {
    str = phonenum;
  } else {
    str = "Not a phone number";
  }
  return(str);
}

console.log(isItANum("hey"));
console.log(isItANum("111111111"));
console.log(isItANum("01111111111"));
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear this solution appears to have helped you. Once you've confirmed this solution solves your problem, please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things on StackOverflow flowing smoothly :)

Answer (score 0):

At the second if, the variable str is already equal to "" . so you need to add another if the str doesnt have any numbers and the value of str is equal to "", its not a phone number.

```js
function isItANum(str) {
var phonenum = str.replace(/[^0-9]+/g,"");

if(str.length===11 && str.indexOf(0)===0) {
 str = str;
} 
else if (str.match(/[a-z]/i)) {
  str = phonenum;
} 

if (str === '') {
  str = "Not a phone number";
}
console.log(str);
return str;
}

isItANum("hey");
```